# Specify Database Connection for cached_db in Django

Tags: django, database, caching

I have a Django webapp, where the session engine is specified to `cached_db` in settings. However I want to use a different database url that what the queries within the app use.

After reading in the documentation for sessions I found there is a variable `SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS` which I set to `cached_db` and added a database connection with the same name:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': ...,
        'USER': ...,
        'PASSWORD': ...,
        'HOST': ...,
        'PORT': ...,
    },
    'cached_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': ...,
        'USER': ...,
        'PASSWORD': ...,
        'HOST': ...,
        'PORT': ...,
    }
}
```

But it seems cached_db is still using the database from default, the reason I believe this is the case because the default's database connection url is a read-only connection, while the cached_db database url is a read/write connection, and in my case I want to separate both connections.

Is this the correct way to separate the connections and define one for cached_db? Or is it not possible in the first place?